# Webservice behind Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I am about to develop a mobile application for 32 customers. Each one of them has its own set of fields, logics and its own webservices. (logic can be for example - what fields to print on page and when). Besides the fields , the rest of the application will be exactly the same for all customers.

I could just develop now 12 different versions of the same application, each version
will be set to specific customer - but this will take me so much time and i am not sure
that its the smart thing to do.

I started to think about a generic pattern that will allow me to create
Only 1 version of mob app. On my server, I will create a business logic layer between each customers webservices and the mob app. that means that mob app will call my webservices - my webservices will call certain customer webservice and perform some logic and return to the mob app the required data in stable format.

That means that

1. mobile app will call my webservice
2. my webservice will call customers service
3. customer webservice will return
4. my webservice will run some logic and return
5. mobile app gets the data and print on screen

So that means that it would take more running time, many seconds. Is that the best way to go with? please advice or offer some alternative Implementation.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, as long as your server has decent connectivity.

Comment: Is there anyway you could cache some of the customer's web service data in your webservice. That could help reduce some round trips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of customer-depending configuration is usually managed by... configuration (and some code-generation). Here following a couple of possible architectural solutions.

## 1 Static configuration of the first type

Put all of your customer-depending stuff in a configuration file (JSON, XML, whatever) and load it when needed to configure the UI and other static aspects of your application. Of course, in this case only static data (filed names and the like) can be managed.

## 2 Static configuration of the second type

Put all of your customer-depending stuff in a configuration file (JSON, XML) and use it to generate your customer-depending application on your server just before installing it. This kind of code-generation is largely used by Ruby-on-Rails and others frameworks. In this case, all of the different aspects of your server-side application can be managed.

## 3 Dynamic configuration

Put all of your customer-depending stuff in a configuration file (JSON, XML, whatever), load it and use it to change the behaviour of your application objects at run-time. Of course, in this case your code must be able to deal accordingly.

## 4 Static configuration, client-side

Put all of your customer-depending stuff in a configuration file (JSON, XML, whatever) and use to generate a different client-side (mobile) application for each and every customer. In this case, the server side can be the same for all of the applications or not. It just depends on you. Of course, generating complete applications for the mobile requires a working "template" that can be used in this way.

As long as I can see, solution number 2 should be the best fit for your needs (because you will have to generate the DB schema, the UI code and the controller logic).